# Где развернуть Java web приложение?

Tags: java, сервер, spring, tomcat, веб-сервер

Написал небольшой сервер на Java. Хотелось бы попробовать делать запросы к нему с телефона (android). Так вот, существуют ли хостинги, где можно БЕСПЛАТНО развернуть свой серв? 
Сам серв совсем небольшой одна war'ка и бд postgresql. Запускал серв локально на Tomcat'e. Интересно все это было бы настроить и запустить в интернете.

Comment: https://www.heroku.com/